# simple scala program not executing on intelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a simple scala program `HelloWorld.scala`

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

I'm using `scala 2.7.3` and on the terminal using `scalac` and `scala` commands it compiles and runs just fine.

I'm using an older version of scala because its compatible with Stanford's TMT library (its a machine learning library)

However, on intelliJ i keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException`

I've tried creating a new scala project and also tried disabling the `make` function inside the run configurations but i get this same error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add scala-sdk to project and download newer version of scala.